# The stream or file "/var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log"

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

I have a Laravel project deployed on `AWS EB` throw `Github` to `AWS Pipeline` all things are fine, but when I visit my domain I got this error:

```
UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in
append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

After some search I got this one:

In the main project dir, I created `.ebextensions` folder contains file called `set.config` that contain:

```
container_commands:
 00_run_bootstrap_command:
  command: "chmod -R 775 storage"
  cwd: "/var/app/staging"

 01_run_bootstrap_command:
  command: "chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache"
  cwd: "/var/app/staging"

02_run_config_cache_command:
  command: "php artisan config:cache"
  cwd: "/var/app/staging"

03_run_config_clear_command:
  command: "php artisan config:clear"
  cwd: "/var/app/staging"

04_run_optimize_command:
  command: "php artisan optimize:clear"
  cwd: "/var/app/staging"
```

When I re-deploy this file still the same error!

Also, I used `chmod -R 777 storage` still same error

Comment: ls -lah who owns the folder or files?   compare that with who owns your index.php file  user:group

Comment: @Cameron Sorry I didnot get you, what do you mean by is '-lah' ? | I deploy the project from local to GitHub  and AWS pipeline deploy the changes to EB

Comment: ohhh gotcha,   I thought you had terminal on the server.   `ls -lah` shows more detail about files and folders.

Comment: I ask because you may have to CHOWN the file or folder as well as your chmod

Comment: I ssh my EB and run `ls -lah` I got this : https://ibb.co/B49RfPH

Comment: I actually found your answer here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/log-file-permissions-error-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-laravel-6  it is related to the user:group

Comment: show me the `ls -lah ` in the /storage/ and the /storage/logs folder

Comment: @Cameron storage: https://ibb.co/pvpctKm | logs:https://ibb.co/vvbTQnh

Comment: yep your issue is laravel.log is owned by root.

Comment: go into the logs folder and type `chown webapp:webapp laravel.log`

Comment: I got this: chown: changing ownership of ‘laravel.log’: Operation not permitted

Comment: may have to use sudo `sudo chown webapp:webapp laravel.log`  (may have to enter your password)

Comment: @Cameron now all files with 'webapp' but still when I change anything in local and deploy the error of log file return back 

Comment: maybe you have to add it in the same spot you add your other chmods (edited my answer below)

Comment: @Cameron I found it! when I run this `sudo chown webapp:webapp laravel.log`  on ssh in logs folder the owns of `laravel.log` changes to webapp, and the website worked but when I change anything from local then deploy the error back, I went to `laravel.log` just check the owns it backed to root!  (means when I deploy anything the owner of `laravel.log` file changes to root)

Comment: @Cameron And that makes the error back again!

Comment: gotcha, I updated my answer below to add the command: : "chown webapp:webapp storage/logs/laravel.log" will that run in your deploy for you?

Comment: @Cameron I already deployed! the whole server stopped! do you want to see the log file?

Comment: @Cameron https://wetransfer.com/downloads/444311abeaf073660b45f853138f8a3f20210702214640/a5f06d

Comment: I would revert back to your inital container_commands,  looks like it failed at app-deploy  which tells me it was that command.  it says more details /var/log/cfn-init.log

Comment: @Cameron Yeah when I revert to my file the server return back to work but still the problem of logs stayed there!

Comment: check this approach,  create a script and run it https://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2015/09/10/quick-tip-writable-laravel-logs-with-elastic-beanstalk/   (of course you need to modify your filepaths in this script example)

Comment: @Cameron   /var/log/cfn-init.log  file says: https://ibb.co/5WX8wcb

Comment: hum guess it wasn't my chown addition.    here is another good article about how you may be able to get writeable laravel logs.  https://spinupwp.com/scaling-laravel-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk-part-3-setting-elastic-beanstalk/     happy coding, I hope you can get it.  A reddit post said they eneded up leveraging third party logs becasue if the same issue.

Comment: did you get it working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will this work?
 `chown $USER:webapp ./storage/logs/ -R`

```
container_commands:
 00_run_bootstrap_command:
  command: "chown webapp:webapp storage/logs/laravel.log"
  cwd: "/var/app/staging"

 01_run_bootstrap_command:
  command: "chmod -R 775 storage"
  cwd: "/var/app/staging"

 02_run_bootstrap_command:
  command: "chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache"
  cwd: "/var/app/staging"

03_run_config_cache_command:
  command: "php artisan config:cache"
  cwd: "/var/app/staging"

04_run_config_clear_command:
  command: "php artisan config:clear"
  cwd: "/var/app/staging"

05_run_optimize_command:
  command: "php artisan optimize:clear"
  cwd: "/var/app/staging"
```

Comment: I'm getting `chown: changing ownership of ‘./storage/logs/’: Operation not permitted`

Comment: @connor leech,  try adding  sudo to the statement.  sudo chown webapp:webapp storage/logs/laravel.log   -not sure if eb will allow that but worth a shot.   If you are trying to change the entire folder you may need chown -R  , otherwise chown a single file without the -R

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when the deployment time the ***laravel.log*** file will not generate, so the ***laravel.log*** file will not get the permission so we can do either container commands or post deployment hooks to create the permission for laravel.log file

***1. Container Commands=>***

```
container_commands:
 01_logfile_permission:
  command: "chown $USER:www-data storage/logs/laravel.log"
  cwd: "/var/app/staging
```

***2. Post Deployment hooks =>***
Create a post deployment hooks, for that you have to create a folder path of .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_permission_logfile.sh and add the below codes to the hooks

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
ech "Giving Permission to Laravel Log file.."
sudo touch /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
sudo chown $USER:www-data /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

[image]

Note: Change the permission as per your requirement..(chown or chmod)